# Send json via POST in ios to a symfony2 server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, symfony

Sorry for the stupid question but I'm getting crazy with that :(

I am trying to send a jSon from a iOs front end to a symfony2 based server via POST.

I dont know what I am doing wrong but there is nothing in the POST.

Here is the front end code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* objeto = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[objeto setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"cliente"];
[objeto setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"usuario"];
[objeto setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:@"producto"];
[objeto setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100] forKey:@"cantidad"];

NSLog(@"objeto %@", [objeto JSONRepresentation]);

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:objeto options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString);


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.com/nueva_venta"]
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]autorelease];

if(connection)
{
    recibeData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

And for example if I do this on the server side:

```
 /**
* Prueba de nueva venta
* @Route("/nueva_venta", name="nueva_venta")
* @Method("POST")
*/
public function nuevaVenta(){

   $request= Request::createFromGlobals();
       return new Response(json_encode($request->request->all()));
    }
```

I get an empty json :(

If I do the request via Javascript instead, it works fine:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        var venta=new Venta();
        venta.cliente=10;
        venta.usuario=1;
        venta.producto=11;
        venta.cantidad=100;



        var capsulaJson={"cliente": venta.cliente,
                            "usuario":venta.usuario,
                            "producto":venta.producto,
                            "cantidad":venta.cantidad};


      var json=capsulaJson.toString();

    $.post("http://xxx.com/nueva_venta", json,
             function (datos) {
                if (datos) {
                    alert(datos);
                }
                else {
                    alert("No funciona :-(");
                }
            }
);
});
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you need to set the content type to `application/json`.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am having exactly the same problem. Do you remember what did you do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.. Dont use jsonData. Use jsonString

```
[request setHTTPBody:jsonString];
```